# How to programmatically load different partial views in same template page in umbraco 7?

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, umbraco7

Can anyone give me an idea about how to do this? My goal is to build a multi step claim submission form where user need to provide information for different sections. I am using VS2015 and Umbraco 7. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look "Creating multi-step forms using a SurfaceController":
https://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2015/2/13/creating-multi-step-forms-using-a-surfacecontroller/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if you want to do it all from one template, it would be best to use a javascript/jquery solution that hides and shows different sections/divs as needed. These divs can be rendered from the partial views. I'm not sure if this works but maybe if you have one Form and all of these divs underneath it, you only need one form button and just submit at the end (I'm pretty positive this would work as the partial view elements would just be rendered as elements inside the form). But if not the values can be stored either in [Jquery Data](https://api.jquery.com/data/), or just using hidden variables, etc.